# How to read only certain (desired) data from more proc/[pid]/status

Tags: bash, ubuntu, process, proc

Lets say I want to extract current `State` (D/R/S/T/Z) and command `Name` from processes with given `PID`.

For example I have this code:

```
pids=$(pidof firefox) #returns all PID-s of firefox processes (random example)

for v in ${pids[*]}
    do
    echo "PID: $v" #here I also want to write status and name of the command (PID, Name, Status)
    done
```

```
more /proc/$$/status
```

returns

```
Name: bash
Umask: 002
State: S (sleeping)
....
Pid: 3234
...
```

From all that information I only need some. I want to know how to extract desired property (`Name`, `Status`,...) from `proc`.

Comment: `${pids[*]}` is referencing an array but `pids=$(pidof ...)` is not an array assignment (it actually assigns the list of pids as a single string to the variable `pids`); assuming you really want to work with an array then consider: `pids=( $(pidof ...) )` and `for v in "${pids[@]}"`

Comment: setting aside the coding issues ... where, under `/proc`, are you expecting to find `Threads`, `Name`, `Status` and `State`?

Comment: if you write `more proc/pid/stat` you can see all the information I described

Comment: then update the question to show: 1) a couple sample pids, 2) the results of `more /proc/pid/stat` for each of the sample pids, and 3) the values you are looking to extract; process info is stored differently for different OS's (eg, on my system the `Name` and `State` values are in `/proc/pid/status`, while `cat /proc/spid/stat` shows `837 (bash) S 832 837 837 8912897 -1 0 103491 103491 0 0 13312 20984 13312 20984
 20 0 0 0 264279 7593984 1542 345`)

Comment: Changed the question a bit, and correction on my comment above: `more /proc/[pid]/status`

Comment: Depending on the information you need, using `ps` or `top` might suffice.  `ps aux | awk '/firefox/ && !/awk/ {print $2" "$8" "$11}' -` or `top -bcn 1 | awk '/firefox/ && !/awk/ {print $1" "$8" "$12}' -`

Answer (score 1):

Using /proc/{pid1, pid2}/status and `grep`:

```
pids=$(pidof firefox); pids=${pids// /,}; grep '^Pid\|Name\|State' < <(bash <<<"cat /proc/{$pids}/status"
```

Sample output:

```
Name:   Isolated Servic
State:  S (sleeping)
Pid:    1052298
Name:   Isolated Web Co
State:  S (sleeping)
Pid:    981127
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to pull out the `Name` and `State`:

```
$ awk '$1=="Name:"{name=$2;next}$1=="State:"{print name,$2;exit}' /proc/$$/status
bash S
```

Fixing issues with OP's code and pulling the `awk` script into the mix:

```
pids=( $(pidof firefox) #returns all PID-s of firefox processes (random example) )

for v in "${pids[*]}"
do
    read -r name state < <(awk '$1=="Name:"{name=$2;next}$1=="State:"{print name,$2;exit}' /proc/${v}/status)
    echo "PID: ${v} / Name: ${name} / State: ${state}"
done
```

Running against OP's single example this should generate:

```
PID: 3234 / Name: bash / State: S
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated calls to `awk` in the possibility that you have a *lot* of elements (unlikely, but hey, maybe it's a server of something...), but mostly as an exercise...

```
$: awk '/^Pid:/{ pid[FILENAME]=$2 } /^Name:/{ name[FILENAME]=$2 } /^State:/{ state[FILENAME]=$2 } END{ for (k in pid) printf "PID:\t%s\tName:\t%s\tState:\t%s\n", pid[k],name[k],state[k] }' $( sed -E 's,(.*),/proc/\1/status,' <(pidof firefox) ) 
PID:    1619    Name:   firefox State:  S
PID:    1620    Name:   firefox State:  S
```

One-liners are ugly - breaking it out -
(I don't actually have pidof or firefox on this laptop, so for full transparency I made a file with a couple pids and used `cat lst` instead of `pidof firefox`, so will just use that below.)

```
$: cat lst # the file
1619
1620
$: sed -E 's,(.*),/proc/\1/status,' <(cat lst) # the status inputs
/proc/1619/status
/proc/1620/status
$: awk '/^Pid:/{ pid[FILENAME]=$2 }
        /^Name:/{ name[FILENAME]=$2 }
        /^State:/{ state[FILENAME]=$2 }
        END{ for (k in pid) printf "PID:\t%s\tName:\t%s\tState:\t%s\n", pid[k],name[k],state[k] }
   ' $( sed -E 's,(.*),/proc/\1/status,' <(cat lst) )
PID:    1619    Name:   mintty  State:  S
PID:    1620    Name:   bash    State:  S
```